# How to write Student’s t Distribution in R?

Tags: r, statistics

```
mu <- 0
sigma <- 1
x <- seq(from = -3, to  =3, by = .1)
nu<-10
y.1 <- gamma*((nu+1)/2)/(sqrt(pi*nu)*gamma*(nu/2))*(1+(t^2)/nu)^-((nu+1)/2)
```

This is the result:

> Error in gamma * ((nu + 1)/2) : non-numeric argument to binary
> operator

I want to write Student’s t Distribution. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gamma` is a function: if you want to apply it to something you only write:

```
gamma((nu + 1)/2)
```

without `*`.
Also you have to replace `t` by `x`:
So this should work:

```
y.1 <- gamma((nu+1)/2) / (sqrt(pi*nu) * gamma(nu/2)) * (1+(x^2)/nu)^-((nu+1)/2)
```

Anyway, the density function of the t-distribution is already implemented in R.
See `?dt`